# Do we need to make thumbnails for uploaded images separately to save memory?

Tags: html, browser

I need two images that based on one image, One will be used as like thumbnail, the other will be drawn of some boxes as original size.

If I control `width` and `height` in `<img>` then it will save memory? Or need to make thumbnail files separately?

Comment: yes likely. the full image has to transfer. it will use more disk space, but it will be more optimal if it isn't drawn to the full size

Comment: No, to resize the image the full one needs to be in memory. Use multiple files and a <picture> element.

Comment: Mmm, I can't use <picture> because this app will be also used internet explorer 10, 11